# itunes app analytics api, is one available?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Does anyone know if the new itunes app analytics has api that I could create an app to pull the data down?  I understand they have iConnect but it does not show as much data as the website does.  We are looking to get info to our VP's and such and would prefer to just create our own front end app.

Is this possible?